# Weird strtotime Conversion of MySQL timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp, strtotime

I have a MySQL field that gives me timestamp in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. The default is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Now, when I try to convert it to Unix timestamp, I get some weird results.

Actually, I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/501415#501415) function to calculate relative time. It outputs negative integers even though MySQL timestamp is only a couple of seconds older. I am at a loss as to what's wrong.

I also found some weird issues. For example, in MySQL,

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1289206455);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1289206455) |
+---------------------------+
| 2010-11-08 14:24:15       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

In PHP CLI:

```
php -r "echo date('Y-m-d h:m:s', 1289206455);"
2010-11-08 09:11:15
```

The supposed output (in both cases) should be: `2010-11-08 02:54:15` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121039/php-strtotime-return-different-value-of-mysql-unix-timestamp/4210698#4210698).

So there seems to be a difference in times in PHP and MySQL. How can I sync them? I am on Ubuntu 11.04 XAMPP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set($zone);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone (@Idg thanks)

Comment: for mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone